# Add Link to CSS StyleSheet

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

where can i add a link to a custom css file in Joomla?

I have tried adding file in index.php but it is valid only for that template and if i load another template i lose the link.

I'm using Joomla 2.5.

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/head-code/25625
EDIT: Better answer:
http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

Comment: The link to a css file should be in the index.php of your template, why not just modify that one?
To not "loose" the link in another template, you need to copy the css file you want, to the template you changed to.

Comment: Jeez, how many templates are you looking to load on your site? Keep separate CSS files for each template

Comment: If your CSS file is related to any component then load inside that components view it will be available for all templates. Otherwise it should be template related and available for current template so you have to copy that to other template if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The right place for a site-wide css should be the template `index.php` file. But since you plan to use several templates, the only other meaningful option is to add it in a system plugin event, instead of spelling out the code you will need to use

```
$document->addStyleSheet($cssurl)
```

However it will be more effective if you just insert it into all your templates.  Also please note that system page cache may not run the events on cache hits.